# VM in proxmox shows more RAM then assigned?

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox, ubuntu-20.04

I assigned 10Gb of ram to my VM but inside the VM it mentions that it has allocated all the ram available in my server (48). Why is this happening? I have a windows VM aswell and there it just shows what I actually set it up with.

[Settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJSd7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you posted shows that you have used 12.6% of 48.47 GB of *disk space*, not memory.

Comment: Hey man, you are completely correct! However another question arises. I have set it to 100gb disk space, so why is it only showing half? https://i.imgur.com/hqbEAfn.png

Comment: You assigned 100GB Storage, but the Filesystem needs to be updated manually, afterwards